# Finite-dimensional Banach space

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

I've a problem with some exercise, namely:

> Show that if *X* is a finite-dimensional Banach space, then every linear functional
>   *f* on *X* is continuous on *X*.
>
> ***Hint***.
>  Use **Proposition:** *Every operator T from a finite-dimensional normed space X into a normed space Y is continuous.*

I don't even know how to start...

Can someone help?

Thanks and regards!

Comment: A linear functional is a linear operator. With codomain the scalar field. So this is a particular case of the proposition you quote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recall that all norms are equivalent in finite dimensional vector space and let $(e_1,\cdots,e_n)$ a basis for $X$ and let 
$$x=\sum_{i=1}^n x_i e_i\in X$$
then we have
$$|f(x)|=\left|\sum_{i=1}^n x_if( e_i)\right|\leq \sum_{i=1}^n |x_i| |f( e_i)|\leq M  \sum_{i=1}^n |x_i|=M||x||_1$$
where 
$$M=\max_{1\le i\le n}|f(e_i)|$$

and then we can deduce.

Comment: Thanks! You really helped me.
The rest also thanks

Comment: You're welcome.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: A linear functional is a linear operator into the scalar field.