# Linear Functional: Continuous?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, vector-spaces, banach-spaces

Given a Banach space: $E$
and chosen a Hamel basis: $\mathcal{B}$

Any vector induces a (noncanonical) algebraic linear functional by:
$$\delta:E\to E^*:\delta_b(b'):=\delta_{b,b'}\text{ defined linearly and extended linearly}$$
How to show that the induced linear functionals are continuous iff the Banach spaces is finite dimensional?

Comment: Well one direction is easy, every linear function defined on a finite dimensional Banach space is continuous. The other direction isn't immediately clear to me yet.

Comment: Why is this so?

Comment: Because the weak topology and the strong topology are always equivalent on a finite dimensional Banach space.

Comment: Ok ^^ but isn't that precisely the question?

Comment: See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/387605/finite-dimensional-banach-space) for a proof that every linear functional on a finite dimensional banach space is continuous.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose that $\mathcal B$ contains a sequence $(b_k)_{k\geqslant 1}$ such that $\lVert b_k\rVert=1$ for each $k$. Define $$L_n(x)=\sum_{k=1}^nk\cdot \delta_{b_k}(x).$$
Then for each $x$, $\sup_{n\geqslant 1}|L_n(x)|$ is finite. Since $\lVert L_n\rVert\geqslant n$, the principle of uniform boundedness implies a contradiction.

Comment: Ok I need to clarify: Is it right when I say that finite dimensional *all* those functionals are continuous and infinite dimensional iff there is at least one being discontinuous? If so does it admittable to change the basis and then do the construction? Because I might (un)luckily start with a basis that goes through not giving any discontinuous functional? Besides, that's a really nice application of the uniform boundedness principle. =D

Comment: Yes it is right.

Comment: But it might happen that one of the functionals is in fact continuous?

Comment: Sorry, one more caveat: I think all we can say is $\Vert L_n\Vert\ge n$, unless I'm missing something.

Comment: You are right. A priori nothing seems to prevent to have a norm greater than $n$ (it will depend on the norm of linear combinations of $b_k$'s).